# How to prove two relations equal in Z3 using HORN logic

Tags: set, z3, smt

I'm using Horn Logic in Z3 to model check CSP (Process Algebra), because Horn Logic is good at dealing with recursive definitions. But, I was stuck in some trick problems. For example, I have the following code:

```
(declare-rel A (Int))
(declare-rel B (Int))

(rule (A 1))
(rule (A 2))

(rule (B 1))
(rule (B 2))
```

Then, how can I prove A and B are equal. This is similar to proving the equivalence of two sets in Z3 using Horn Logic.

Please, anyone can give me a clue? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is an engine that supports stratified negation.
It works for finite domains only. Using stratified negation you can
check equivalence. For example:

```
(declare-rel A ((_ BitVec 8)))
(declare-rel B ((_ BitVec 8)))
(declare-rel q ())

(rule (A #x01))
(rule (A #x02))

(rule (B #x01))
(rule (B #x02))

(declare-var x (_ BitVec 8))

(rule (=> (and (A x) (not (B x))) q))
(rule (=> (and (B x) (not (A x))) q))

(query q)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Because Horn logic does not supports Array operations, I have to simulate the set theory using the relations. Initially, I use (A a true) (A b true) (A c false) to represent the set including a and b if the alphabet is a, b and c. But this approach is sometimes very awkward when the domain is uncertain. I'll refine two processes containing some lists which are generated by some rules. So, I need the negation to find out whether one list in P which is not in Q. It seems the BitVector can check two sets with finite elements. Finally, stratified negation supports BitV only?